# Why is Blender still rendering the old image after the .blend file has been changed

Tags: rendering, image

The first image is the old .blend file. I'm running blender 2.76 on linux mint
The original file is the one that shows up when I type F12

[image: the old .blend file render]

This is the new file.

As you can see the  difference is in the orange (selected).

There is no video sequence file to remove as a previous answer suggeted.

[image: the changed area of the file is selected and is in orange.]

Comment: Did you add a new shapekey after making the changes in edit mode?

Comment: do you have any old keyframes?

Comment: please add more information on your issue. From the images alone is hard to understand what is different. An easier way to get to get your isssue fixed is to share your blend file.

Comment: @TLousky No shapekeys used at all

Comment: @cegaton, I sent you the .blend file in a prior question. Can't remember how I did the upload.

Comment: use http://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/ you'll get a link to the uploaded file. Then edit your question and add the link to it.

Comment: I remember the file. Were you using a different user name?

Comment: The question was posed by someone else.

Comment: [<img src="http://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/embedImage.png?bid=625" />](http://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/b/625/)

Comment: And no, no keyframes.